# Unable to connect to Document DB using .NET SDK hosted on Azure: The input authorization token can't serve the request

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have created a documentDB and am able to manage and query it when running a WebAPI project on my local machine.

However once I deploy this application to Azure, it stops working.

I've enabled logging and add a bunch of trace commands and have finally confirmed the failure point.

It is with this line:

```
var database = Client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(db => db.Id == databaseId).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();
```

The following error is returned from DocumentDB:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, 
and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get sat, 16 may 2015 01:41:19 gmt
```

Again, this works fine locally. I am hitting the API from from an angular app and data is returned from the DocumentDB.

But on Azure, no dice.

From trace logging I can see that the Document Client is created successfully and the correct AuthKy and Endpoint are retreived from the app settings.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Same question on MSDN forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d1da1002-9971-47e2-a961-b48be986bef8/unable-to-connect-to-document-db-using-net-sdk-hosted-on-azure-the-input-authorization-token-cant?forum=AzureDocumentDB

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the clock time from the machine you're running on is accurate. If it's more than 5 minutes behind (or 15 minutes ahead), you'll get auth errors.